# How to bind jquery datatable to model (list)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I need a datatable with CRUD operations. How do I map the data model to the data table?

Here is my controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Q_FourthPage()
    // GET request: either answers exist, or it's the first time this page is loaded
    // if answers exist, the table must be populated
    {
        // create model matrix
        var vmmatrix = new List<Models.Capacity>();
        var vm = new ViewModels.Q4_Answer_VM();
        vm.Matrix = vmmatrix;
        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["qstid"]);
        if (db.Capacities.Any(x => x.Questionnaire_ID == userid))
        {
            // add capacities
            vm.Matrix.AddRange(db.Capacities.Where(x => x.Questionnaire_ID == userid).ToList());
        }

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Here is the table inside the view:

```
@model MyANTon.ViewModels.Q4_Answer_VM

<table class="grid" id="datatable" style="table-layout:fixed">
    <thead>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
            <th style="vertical-align: middle">Nr.</th>
            <th>Last</th>
            <th>Quelle</th>
            <th>Ziel</th>
            <th>Frequenz [/h]</th>
            <th>Abstand [m]</th>
            <th>Zeile löschen</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Here is the javascript which until now only adds a row with a simple input. In this input I want to be able to add an element to the data model.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    debugger; 
    var t = $('#datatable').DataTable();
    $('#BtnPlus').on('click', function () {        
    t.row.add([
        '<th><input type="text"/></th>',
        '<th><input type="text"/></th>',
        '<th><input type="text"/></th>',
        '<th><input type="text"/></th>',
        '<th><input type="text"/></th>',
        '<th><input type="text"/></th>',
        '<th><input type="button" id="BtnPlus" name="BtnMinus" value="-" align="center" style="vertical-align: middle" /></th> '
    ]).draw();
    counter++;
});

});
```

My question is: how do I bind the inputs to the model? Similar to this, how do I bind the model to the GET request when loading the page for the first time? I need to prepopulate the table.
I guess this is where ajax calls come into play; unfortunately, I do not really know where to start.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use ajax calls to the server and append date to the datatable, that way is more reliable

Comment: Hi Jerry. Do you mean I should have the controller method return a list of ajax objects? Can you link me an example of what you mean?